# Get the depth of a node in a Ternary Tree Using The Indexes in Array Implementation of Trees

Tags: python, data-structures, tree, ternary-tree

Let's assume we create a Ternary tree using an array implementation. The root is stored in the index 1, the left child is stored in index = 3(index)-1, middle child is stored in 3(index), and right child is stored in 3(index)+1. So for example. Assume the following Ternary Tree.

```
                                    A
                    B               C             D
                 E  F  G         H  I  J       K  L  M
```

The array implementation would be `[None, A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, J, K, L, M]`

If we take F for random, F is the middle child go B, and B is the left child of A. A has an index of 1, so B has an index of 2, so F has an index of 6.

My question is, how can I get the depth from the indexes. F has an index of 6 and a depth of 2. If this was a binary tree, the depth would simply be equal to `int(math.log(index, 2))`. What is the equation for the depth for a ternary tree, I can't think of any.

Comment: So in a ternary tree a node has 3 children, not 2 as in a binary tree. Have you considered changing `2` to `3` in that line of code?

Comment: Yes that doesn't work

Comment: What's wrong with it?

Comment: @mkrieger1 it doesn't work for indices starting with 2.

Answer (score 0):

The number of nodes in level `k` is `3**k`, for level 0 it's 1, for level 1 it's 3, for level 2 it's 9, and so on.
The total number of nodes in `k` levels is the sum of arithmetic progression:

```
sum(i in [0;k], 3**i) = (1 + 3**k)*(k+1) / 2
```

For a node index `N` you need to find such `k` that:

```
(1 + 3**k)*(k+1)/2 <= N < (1 + 3**(k+1))*(k+2) / 2
```

I would suggest binary search to find `k` given `N`, as it's a programming problem, not mathematical.

But you can also try to solve the equation by taking the natural logarithm of its parts, for `N>1` it should keep the inequality sign. I'll leave this to you as an excersize, otherwise you can ask in the Mathematics stack exchange.

Answer (score 0):

The formula is `int(math.log(2*index - 1, 3))`

You can derive it as follows:

Each level has a number of nodes that is a power of 3.
So the position of the last node in a level is a sum of such powers, which forms a [geometric series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series#Closed-form_formula). This means the index of the last node on level  (zero based) is (3─1)/2. Solving this to , and taking into account the dummy entry in the array, this gives the final solution at the top.